# Intrinsic Definition of $^\sigma\alpha$, where $\alpha$ a covariant $k$-tensor and $\sigma\in S_k$

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $\mathcal T^k(V^*)$ be the set of all the covariant $k$-tensors on $V$.

The symmetric group $S_k$ acts on $\mathcal T^k(V^*)$ as follows: Given $\alpha\in \mathcal T^k(V^*)$ and $\sigma\in S_k$, we define $^\sigma\alpha\in \mathcal T^k(V^*)$ as:

$$^\sigma\alpha(v_1,\ldots, v_n)=\alpha(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(n)}), \quad \forall  v_1,\ldots, v_n\in V$$

Here we are interpretting a $k$-tensor on $V$ as $k$-multilinear map on $V\times \cdots \times V$.

> ***Question.*** I a wondering how could we define $^\sigma\alpha$ without thinking of tensors as multilinear maps.

A $k$-tensor on $V$ can be defined using the universal property of tensor products with no reference to multilinear maps. I am looking for a similar description of the action of $S_k$ on $\mathcal T^k(V^*)$.

Can somebody help?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what is your guess? How does $\sigma$ act on a pure tensor $v_1 \otimes \dotsc \otimes v_n$?

Comment: Ah! Thanks. It should be $v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$.

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be $v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}$.

Comment: That's right --.